# What is the longest streak of a team being in playoffs, and what is the current ongoing streak?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason

With teams slowly but surely qualifying for playoffs, I'm wondering:

What is the longest streak of being in playoffs in the NHL? And what is the current, still running, longest streak?

Answer (score 1):

The longest ever NHL playoffs streak belongs to the [Boston Bruins](https://records.nhl.com/records/playoff-team-records/appearances/team-most-consecutive-seasons-playoff) who made the playoffs from 1967-68 season to 1995-96.

The current longest playoff appearance belongs to the [Pittsburgh Penguins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NHL_franchise_post-season_appearance_streaks) who've made the playoffs since 2006-07 season (14 seasons).

Comment: Source (and updates): [Wikipedia's List of NHL franchise post-season appearance streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NHL_franchise_post-season_appearance_streaks)